# Why isnt a fan pushing air in the direction of the fans blades?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

According to newtons law of reaction every force has a reaction in the opposite direction so why i dont feel any airflow near the sides of a fan, the fans blades are located in the sides of a fan, the fans blades are moving in a circular motion so the air should move in a circular motion too right? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are fans that push air or make the air move radially, these are centrifugal fans.

But the classic “propellor” type fan works the same as on an aircraft and causes an axial flow, the office fan blows towards you while the aircraft on blows to the rear so it moves forwards.

Given the picture, the air is pushed as the blade rotates due to the angle, or more correctly, the pitch of the blade.

Comment: I mean how does the fan blow air towards you, there is no force in that direction, the fans blades arent facing toward you.

Comment: Perhaps you need to show an image of the fan you are talking about.

Comment: You will find a more technical explanation here: http://www.personal.psu.edu/cxc11/508/PROF_T_CAROLUS_LECTURES/Lecture1(N09_085A).pdf

Comment: Just for interest centrifugal fans: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/centrifugal-fan

Comment: Thank you so much, also something else was wondering me, when you change the direction of the fan from counter clockwise to clockwise,the fan pulls air instead of pushing it, is it because of the angle?

Comment: It’s always because of the pitch - if you put the blades flat then the air will not move...